# Current Timestamp in Azure Databricks Notebook in EST

Tags: python, datetime, pyspark, python-datetime

I need the current timestamp in EST but the `current_timestamp()` is returning PST.

Tried the following code but it's not working and showing 6 hours before EST time:

```py
# Import the current_timestamp function
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_utc_timestamp
    
# Set the timezone to EST
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "EST")
    
# Get the current timestamp in EST
current_timestamp_est = spark.sql("SELECT from_utc_timestamp(current_timestamp(), 'EST') as current_timestamp_est")
    
# Show the current timestamp in EST
current_timestamp_est.show(truncate = False)
```

Also tried the below code. But the time is coming as `2024-03-11 23:16:04.589275-04:00`. Why it's coming with `-4:00`? Is there a way to get rid of the `-4:00`?

```py
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

est = timezone('US/Eastern')
now_est = datetime.now(est)
#now_est1 = now_est[:26]
print(now_est)
```

Any other way to get the current timestamp in EST in a variable?

Comment: The reason is that you're setting your `timeZone` to `EST` then you're using the `from_utc_timestamp` transformation which is causing spark to take the `current_timestamp` in `EST` timezone as the `UTC` timestamp. In your `spark.sql` statement, just use `current_timestamp()` without the `from_utc_timestamp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of the `-04:00` you can just use [`.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) in your second approach:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

est = timezone('US/Eastern')
now_est = datetime.now(est).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print(now_est)

Output:
2024-04-04 09:42:58
```

Now, for the first approach instead of setting `EST` as the timezone - it's preferred to point out a location around the globe like `America/New_York` to get rid of the offset value `-04:00` as follows:

```py
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "America/New_York")
current_timestamp_est = spark.sql("SELECT current_timestamp() as current_timestamp_est")

current_timestamp_est.show(truncate=False)

Output:
+--------------------------+
|current_timestamp_est     |
+--------------------------+
|2024-04-04 09:42:12.082136|
+--------------------------+
```

Comment: pytz has been deprecated for a while now, please use [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html). Also, time zone identifier 'US/Eastern' is obsolete. use a country/city - style specifier such as "America/New_York".

Comment: I just used the same code by O.P. and added `.strftime()` to let them know how they can get rid of `-04:00` (which was the ask - so didn't change anything else) in the second approach (the first code block in my answer) and if you notice in the second code block I am already using `America/New_York`.

Anyways, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: You know how things go, code gets copied from accepted answers on SO etc. So sometimes I feel obliged to recommend up-to-date practices ;-)